# issue:comparing and object with array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a scenario where I need to compare object property called 'name' with array of strings with same name and get the length of the compared value based on name. I don't understand what I need to compare.

Here is my code below:

```
$scope.pushRec=[];
   //----comparing response and response.club properties
    angular.forEach($scope.aResponse, function(value, key) {
        $scope.aClub=value.club;
        console.log($scope.aClub);
        console.log(value.recruiter);
        $scope.aResRec=value.recruiter;
    });
    //----if it matches push in to pushRec
     angular.forEach($scope.aClub, function(value, key) {

        console.log(value.recruiter);
        $scope.aRec=value.recruiter;
           console.log($scope.aClub);
        if($scope.aResRec[0] ==  $scope.aRec){
            $scope.pushRec.push( $scope.aClub);
            console.log( $scope.pushRec.length);
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you add comments in your code to have better idea.

Comment: @VivekSingh added comments

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this.

```
 $scope.pushRec=[];
   //----comparing response and response.club properties
    angular.forEach($scope.aResponse, function(value, key) {
        $scope.aClub= angular.copy(value.club);
        console.log($scope.aClub);
        console.log(value.recruiter);
        $scope.aResRec=angular.copy(value.recruiter);
    });
    //----if it matches push in to pushRec
     angular.forEach($scope.aClub, function(value, key) {

        console.log(value.recruiter);
        $scope.aRec=value.recruiter;
           console.log($scope.aClub);
        if($scope.aResRec[0] ===  $scope.aRec){
            $scope.pushRec.push( $scope.aClub);
            console.log( $scope.pushRec.length);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.